# How to create a sequence diagram or class diagram for dart code?

Tags: dart

Is there a way to create a sequence diagram or class diagram for dart code? Or any other useful way to visualize the structure (or a vague programmflow) of a dart application.

edit: here is the feature request. If you think that it is a good idea, star it. http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6558&q=sequence%20diagram&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: Interesting question. I haven't tried, but maybe [UML Class Diagram](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/uml_class_diagram.html) together with [the Dart plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=6351) will do the work?

Comment: Dart definitly needs such a tool!! It is so much easier to understand and communicate your code to others. A stacktrace of called methods and created objects for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything for Dart that will feed your code to Graphviz, but there are two tools in Dart Editor that I find helpful: Tools/Outline and Tools/Callers.

Doing something that would generate a pretty diagram with Graphviz sounds like it would be a great contribution to Dart! If it's been done in the Eclipse world before, then it's probably possible to hack Dart Editor to do it. Alternatively, you can file a bug on dartbug.com requesting the feature.

Comment: I think this is really an essential feature that dart has to have!! If it is possible to debug (what is awesome), it should be possible to track the progress through an application.

Comment: I agree that that would be nice to have. You should create a feature request on dartbug.com.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation generation tool can extract the program structure, you might want to check it's code.  I'm not sure, but it probably uses the VM to parse the source code into an AST and navigate it for generation of the doc.